# Work, energy and power

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, photons, work, power

A load of mass $m$ slides down a smooth plane with inclination title from point $A$ to $B$. The same mass is then dropped from $A$ to $C$.

Could anyone decipher this $\downarrow$. I've edited the equations but this is beyond me.

In which of the station is more in each case considering the work done along AC and AB work done at $W = \int_A^C F*ds$ $=mgh$ work done $W=\int_A^BF*ds = mg\sin\theta<AB>$ where $<AB> = h/\sin\theta$.

[image: pls use the diagram in the pic to solve it.]

Pls I need the answer before 3:00pm today it's urgent pls pls pls

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. It is not a homework solution forum.  You must show an effort to solve a problem to see where you are stuck to get help with homework. BTW, 3:00pm very much depends on your time zone. And the question is not clear, I dont understand...

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is a badly asked question, and I do not know what exactly are you looking for, I'll try.
You know that $W = \int_A^BF*ds$ where $F$ is the force excreted and $ds$ is the path on which the force is acting. In your case, $ds$ is constant so it turns into $s$ and then you have $W=F*s$.
If you drop the mass from a height $h$ you get $W=mgh$ where
$F=mg$ and
$s=h$
If you slide if from an incline, you have $W=mg h\sin\theta/\sin\theta$
Where $F=mg\sin\theta$ and $s=h/sin\theta$ so you get $W=mgh$, same as if you were dropping it from height $h$.
On the inclined plane you know that the work is equal to the energy difference from top to bottom. Energy on top when mass is at rest is $0$.
Energy when it reaches the ground is equal to the potential energy $E=-mgh$ and therefore $W = 0- (-)mgh = mgh$.
In the case of a free fall you have the same scenario. Energy at the top is $0$ while energy on the bottom is $mgh$.
Were there friction in the equation, then the work would be different in case of inclined plane (you would have energy loss).

Comment: Tanks but pls u didn't give the final answer

Comment: @user147658 This is not a homework answering service.  **You** need to generate the final answer.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: A load of mass m slide down a smooth plane with inclination title from point A to B the same mass is then drop from A to C in which of the station is more in each case considering the work done along AC and AB work done at AC =forces × distance =mg × h [=mgh] work done AB=force and distance..=mg × ABsin. [Mg ABsin] [￼using the graph

Comment: Yes, I know but you do understand that it is incomprehensible.
Just the question part because this is either a badly translated question or a faulty one. Just give me the question part, only that and translate it as best you can.

Comment: A 2kg body is allowed to roll down in a inclined plane 4m long with an angle of inclination 30...pls answer now

Comment: What is the question, what is needed,asked for? Do you need to calculate the work of the said mass? Then the work is $mgh$ if you slide it down. Same when you drop it. $W=2kg*4m*sin(30)*g$ where $4m*sin(30)$ is the height.